# UILabel text is truncated if I add some of accesory type

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel

I have cell with two of `UILabel`. Looks like this:

[image]

And when I run the simulator it is looks well:

[image]

but if I add disclosure indicator and then update constraints not to overlay it so my simulator looks like this:

[image]

And my storyboard settings are:

[image]

if I change "Line Breaks" in IB to other It doesn't solve the problem.

How can I avoid such behaviour and see disclosure indicator and multiline `UILabel` a the same time?

Looks like the main point of in this issue is accessory, because with the same constraints but without accessory it is displayed properly, but with accessory it is not.

What can I do to display it properly?

Comment: Looks like your label will require 3 lines to display the text correctly in this case due to the width being even shorter once you add the disclosure.

Comment: You can increase the cell height to fit the label height.

Comment: I increased it, but it doesn't try to fill even 2 lines.

Comment: It looks like that it is not usual way to use indicator in multilines UILabels

Comment: You can decrease font size or increase cell height according to text size(height) to properly display whole text.

Comment: Sure I can, but it is not really useful to change the font every time to fit the content. The UILable should take so many line so it needs, that is the point

Comment: In storyboard, hope you have reposition the value label after added the Indicator. I just tried and it and value label is multiline. make sure the value label height have enough height to show multiline text. and cell height >= label height

Comment: All constraints are correct I suppose, because they are the same as with accessory suggested ones. But the same constraints with different cell representations (with/without accessory) has different result in simulator. I put the same UILabel height as cell has.